# Add Firefix layers to yocto using Hob

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

Using Yocto 1.7 (Dizzy), I try to use this layer : https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-browser
I've done that :

```
$ cd poky
$ git clone https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-browser.git
$ cd meta-browser 
$ git checkout -b dizzy
```

Then I launch Hob, add the new layer, but I have this error : `No recipes available for: /home/user/poky/meta-browser/recipes-gnome/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon_2.32.1.bbappend`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

meta-browser has a dependency (according to its README) on meta-openembedded. gnome-settings-daemon comes from the meta-gnome layer in [meta-openembedded](http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/).

So you have two choices:

1) Add meta-gnome to your bblayers-setup.

2) If nothing really needs gnome-settings-daemon, you can add recipes-gnome/ gnome-settings-daemon to BBMASK, to hide that bbappend. Search for BBMASK in [Yocto docs](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html) for a better understanding. You should be able to use something similar to:

```
BBMASK .= "|meta-browser/recipes-gnome"
```

Which of these two solutions you need to chose, depends on whether firefox (or something firefox depends on) needs gnome-settings-daemon or not.